# Target element with specific attribute in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to target all the button which has a buttonid starts from tab_btn(number)

Is there a way to select element in css this way. I cannot make use of jquery as CSS is only the restriction.

```
<input id="FormControl_V1_I1_S1_I1_B1" scriptclass="Button" class="dh_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0 dj_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0" formid="FormControl" originalid="V1_I1_S1_I1_B1" tabindex="0" title="" buttonid="tab_btn1" value="General" type="button">

<input id="FormControl_V1_52_J1_I1_B1" scriptclass="Button" class="dh_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0 dj_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0" formid="FormControl" originalid="V1_I1_S1_I1_B1" tabindex="0" title="" buttonid="tab_btn2" value="General" type="button">
```

Class and other attribute wont be constant here, But the ID will have a series starting tab_btn1, tab_btn2 etc

Comment: Why you tagged jQuery ?

Comment: Jquery users might have an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute selector in css. The **[attribute^="value"]** selector is used to select elements whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

```css
input[buttonid^= "tab_btn"] {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="FormControl_V1_I1_S1_I1_B1" scriptclass="Button" class="dh_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0 dj_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0" formid="FormControl" originalid="V1_I1_S1_I1_B1" tabindex="0" title="" buttonid="tab_btn1" value="General" type="button">

<input id="FormControl_V1_52_J1_I1_B1" scriptclass="Button" class="dh_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0 dj_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0" formid="FormControl" originalid="V1_I1_S1_I1_B1" tabindex="0" title="" buttonid="tab_btn2" value="General" type="button">

<input id="FormControl_V1_H2_M1_I1_B1" scriptclass="Button" class="dh_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0 dj_LmyGLHecqegKZ42V_0" formid="FormControl" originalid="V1_J1_T1_I1_B1" tabindex="0" title="" buttonid="tab2" value="General" type="button">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do `[id^="tab_btn"]` as a selector. It will target all IDs beginning with `tab_btn`

See the docs https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: `[id^=tab_btn]` should be `[id^="tab_btn"]`.

Comment: There is no need to use the quotes

Comment: If it were being used as a selector from JavaScript the quotes would be nessecery, but yea css has no such requirement

Comment: It isn't needed in javascript either, at least not jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Check this example:

Set a background color on all  elements that have a class attribute value that begins with "test":

```
div[class^="test"] {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```